# Native Heap Memory size increase when open the keyboard - android

Tags: java, android

I've loaded 3 `ListView`s and one `EditText` on my layout.

When I touch the `EditText`, the keyboard opens. At that instant I check the memory size using this code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long vmAlloc =  rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory();
long nativeAlloc = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();

Log.d("Memory",className+"Maximum   : "+formatMemoeryText(rt.maxMemory()));

Log.d("Memory",className+"VM Heap   : "+formatMemoeryText(rt.totalMemory()));
Log.d("Memory",className+"NativHeap : "+formatMemoeryText(Debug.getNativeHeapSize()));

Log.d("Memory",className+"VM    (A) : "+formatMemoeryText(vmAlloc));
Log.d("Memory",className+"Nati(A)   : "+formatMemoeryText(nativeAlloc));

Log.d("Memory",className+"TotalAll  : "+formatMemoeryText(nativeAlloc+vmAlloc));
Log.d("Memory", "----------------------------------------------------");
```

Every time the keyboard opens the native heap size increases. Eventually the app will force close.

I've tried:

```
System.gc();
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

But it only reduces it by about 0.5-1MB. The very next time I open the keyboard it increases by 20-30MB.

How do I prevent the app from closing or clear its native heap memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that your app is crashing due to keyboard causing out of memory, there must be some thing in your program which is causing memory leak
 **yes** when you request keyboard by focusing on input field or programatically it allocate memory but not so huge that cause your program to crash, please review your code, and find memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you that the device orientation is not changed when android keybard is opened. because if it is then your activity will be recreated whole and may cause memory leak if you any object is holding reference of your activity.